# Use a separate dataframe to assign groups to another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, r-plotly

I am currently working with genetic data where the headers are cell sample names. There are 2 samples from each type of cell collected, and they need to be plotted in a box plot. Due to inconsistent sample naming, I am using a separate .csv file where the user writes the sample name and the group it belongs to. I am trying to use the `group_by()` function to access the sample data but then use the grouping information from the other .csv file. Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
Cell Sample Data CSV:                     
Sample A1         Sample A2    Sample B1     Sample B2
1                 3            3             5
```

```
Grouping CSV
Samples           Group     
Sample A          1           
Sample B          1           
Sample C          2
Sample D          2
```

My current idea is doing something like this

```
library(dplyr)
groupFile <- data %>% group_by(groupFile$Group)
```

however that didn't work, and I am stuck at how to make the data correspond to the grouping file.

Note: I previously uploaded this question without sample data and code and it was closed. I'm hoping this describes the problem well enough.

Answer (score 0):

First let's improve your example cell sample data by including samples that are in different groups:

```
celldata <- structure(list(`Sample A1` = 1L, `Sample A2` = 3L, `Sample B1` = 3L, 
                           `Sample B2` = 5L, `Sample C1` = 6L, `Sample C2` = 7L), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

And your groups data:

```
groupdata <- structure(list(Samples = c("Sample A", "Sample B", "Sample C", "Sample D"), 
                            Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
                            row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Life will be much easier with data in "long" format rather than wide, and with everything in the one dataframe.

We can use `tidyr::gather` to reshape the cell data, then `dplyr::mutate` to get `Samples` without the numeric suffixes and finally, `dplyr::left_join` to bring samples and groups together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

celldata %>% 
  gather(Sample, Value) %>% 
  mutate(Samples = gsub("\\d+", "", Sample)) %>% 
  left_join(groupdata)
```

Result:

```
     Sample Value  Samples Group
1 Sample A1     1 Sample A     1
2 Sample A2     3 Sample A     1
3 Sample B1     3 Sample B     1
4 Sample B2     5 Sample B     1
5 Sample C1     6 Sample C     2
6 Sample C2     7 Sample C     2
```

Now you can group on `Group`. Depending on what you want to do next, you may want to convert `Group` to a factor. And if you're using `ggplot2`, you may not even need to `group_by`.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

celldata %>% 
  gather(Sample, Value) %>% 
  mutate(Samples = gsub("\\d+", "", Sample)) %>% 
  left_join(groupdata) %>% 
  mutate(Group = factor(Group)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Group, Value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color  = Samples)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi neilfws, thanks for replying. I should have clarified this better when I said inconsistent naming but the sample names I'm using are [b05 Neutrophil1 Exp2, b07 Neutrophil3 Exp2, b10 Monocyte1 Exp2, b11 Monocyte2 Exp2, a01 brain microglia1 Exp1 m, a02 brain microglia2 Exp1 m, a06 peritoneum Mac1 Exp1 m, a07 peritoneum Mac2 Exp1 m, b08 Spleen Mac1 Exp2, b09 Spleen Mac2 Exp2, b04 Kupffer Exp2, b15 Kupffer2 Exp2, a12 LI Mac2 Exp1 m, a13 LI Mac3 Exp1 m, a10 SI Mac3 Exp1 m, a11 SI Mac4 Exp1 m, b02 lung Exp2, b17 lung mac2 Exp2, so the method of removing the numeric suffixes isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a bracket after the last sample name, but there should be one after lung mac2 exp2.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can figure out a way to use `mutate` that works with your sample names. If you want working solutions, it's important to use example data that looks like your real data.